# Injectiveness of $M\otimes_RS\to N$ and linear independence

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, tensor-products

If $f:M\to N$ is map of modules over a (commutative) ring $R$ (edit: and $M$ is torsion free), then $f$ is injective if and only if $(f(v_i))_i\subset N$ is linearly independent whenever $(v_i)_i\subset M$ is linearly independent. I am wondering if this extends to the following setting: Let $R\to S$ be a map of commutative rings, $M$ a torsion free $R$-module, $N$ an $S$-module and $f:M\to N\rvert_R$ a map of $R$-modules. Question:

> Is $\tilde{f}:M\otimes_RS\to N$ injective iff every $R$-linearly independent set in $M$ gets mapped (by $f$) to an $S$-linearly independent set in $N$?
> If not, under what conditions on $R\to S$ does this hold?

For $\Rightarrow$: Suppose that $v_1,\dots,v_n\in M$ is $R$ linearly independent but $\sum_{i}\lambda_if(v_i)=0$ is a nontrivial linear relation in $N$ with $\lambda_i\in S$. Then set $v:=\sum_{i}v_i\otimes\lambda_i\in M\otimes_RS$. We have $\tilde{f}(v)=0$ but is $v\ne0$? If $R\to S$ is flat then yes. ($R=M=\Bbb Z,S=N=\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ should be a counterexample, so some further condition like flatness is definitely needed for this direction)

For $\Leftarrow$: If $v:=\sum_{i}v_i\otimes\lambda_i\in M\otimes_RS$ and $f(v)=0$, then assuming that not all $\lambda_i=0$, the $v(v_i)$ are $S$-linearly dependent, so the $v_i$ are $R$-linearly dependent, but I don't see how this would imply that $v=0$, since the $\lambda_i$ might not come from the coefficients of the relation satisfied by the $v_i$ over $R$.

Comment: Maybe in the first statement of the question I need that $M$ is torsion free